# API взаимодействия приложения и FB, аналогичное ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, facebook, facebook-api, auth

При взаимодействии своего приложения и ВК, чтобы не производить авторизацию пользователя на своем сервере, можно проверить соответствие auth_key на правильность:

auth_key = md5(api_id + '_' + viewer_id + '_' + api_secret)

где 
auth_key – это ключ, необходимый для авторизации пользователя на стороннем сервере.

api_id – это id запущенного приложения.

viewer_id – это id пользователя, который просматривает приложение.
api_secret - Защищенный секретный ключ.

Вопрос... Есть ли аналогичная формула для FB. И если есть, то можно ее описать (и что и откуда берется) или дать конкретную ссылку на нее (формулу) и описание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогичная формула для FB есть. Она немного сложнее, но, в целом, подход тот же. Описывать ее, наверное, не имеет смысла. А ознакомиться можно на [этой странице](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login) в разделе `"Подписанный запрос"`.